# Floors and walls in unheated garage/workshop

Tags: walls, flooring, garage

On my lot I have a garage which I use for various types of storage. At the moment the floor is paved with [concrete bricks](https://dombud.eu/kostka-brukowa/242-kostka-brukowa-h1-6cm.html), and the walls are made of [concrete fence](https://www.budomat-labiszyn.pl/en/images/ogrodzenia-betonowe/ogrodzenia-betonowe-05.jpg). Suffice to say it's not the prettiest and I am trying to come up with ways to make it a little bit comfier.

The main challenge is that it's unheated, will never be heated and I live in Poland where over the year the temperatures go from -15°C to 30°C (5°F to 86°F).

**What types of materials could I use to make even and clean floor and walls?** I don't particularly mind if overtime they'll get a little crooked, have cracks or whatnots.

For floors I was thinking about floor panels, not solid wood but fiberwood (don't know how those are called in English, the ones that are made of dense fiberwood meant to imitate real wood panels but thinner). Unfortunately I've read a lot of conflicting opinions about those so I am not confident it'd work well, plus it also raises the question what to put underneath them, to keep them even and avoid moisture from the ground destroying them, if that even is an issue.

For the walls I was thinking plasterboard, finished with wall putty and painted over, probably with paint that allows moisture to pass through.

But those ideas come from very uneducated place.

Comment: Good questions, but maybe too broad for a Q&A site. It's going to come down to your prerogative with respect to cost, effort, and availability. Frankly the only good solutions that come to mind are a concrete slab (in place of the paver bricks), and framed and sheathed walls on that. lining your concrete walls. Good luck. By the way, [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question) isn't what most people think. :)

Comment: Thanks, in retrospect I should've known about begging the question not being what I think it was because I kind of knew it was a fallacy. I wonder about it being too broad though, I feel like the restriction to "should be cheap and sturdish, doesn't have to be super pretty" narrows it down pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

If the concrete brick block floor is dry you might be able to put a floating floor on it a nice thick pad for insulation the floor needs to be flat. There are many different brands and many snap together, one of the first of these I did back in 2000 is still in good shape and we have had 3 dogs. 
The walls could be covered with furring strips and Sheetrock attached to the strips, then finished and painted. You said no heat so I would not waste $ on insulation. Both projects are DIY for even a new person and a garage is a good space to start and build your skills.

Comment: The floor is dry, but we've only been living here since August, so I don't yet know how it handles all seasons. There is some insulation on the outside, styrofoam covered with a hard finish. As for Sheetrock, google says it's a brand of drywall. Is it just any kind of drywall or does it have to be one that has specific properties? That brand is not available here

Comment: I'll be surprised if you find a product that claims to be durable on such a fluid base as pavers. Most are designed for over concrete slabs.

Comment: Sheetrock (aka drywall) is a generic term many different brands some are moisture resistant , if pavers are set on a good base they are not fluid at all. Adding a layer above will actually reduce problems with a marginal base. 2 homes back I had a home we could not pour a concrete driveway because of city right of way, I packed crushed rock and laid pavers then sand and I did have to repack 1 small area About a year later but I was driving over it with by step van that weighed in at 12k. Add another layer of material that spreads the load across multiple pavers No problem as long as it is dry

Comment: I'm fairly sure that a layer of thick insulation foam (which you put under floating floor anyway afaik) or two should probably be enough to even things out for a garage use.